# Sql 2005 alternate of Access query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Hi I am stuck in the following query which I have written for Access and working properly. But when I am running it through SQL 2005, it gives me error (**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'**).

I have been through similar questions but there was no solution to my problem.

Here is the Access query.

```
select iif(ISBN IS Null,"1","0") as OK from products
```

Please need a SQL 2005 version.

This might be a basic query but i am new to sql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mcalex it is available on sql server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `CASE` instead.

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN ISBN IS Null
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS OK 
FROM   products
```

but [`IIF` should work if you are using SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx).

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN expression1
            THEN 0
            ELSE 
                CASE 
                    WHEN expression2
                    THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                END
       END AS OK 
FROM   products
```

Comment: Thats great. But what if I use neasted iif(exp,"0",iif(exp,"2","3))?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to you a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression to replace the `IIf()`. SQL Server 2005 does not have an `IIF()` function:

```
select case when ISBN is null then 1 else 0 end as OK
from products
```

If you have additional `IIF()` statements then you can nest them:

```
select 
  case 
     when ISBN is null 
     then 1 
     else 
       case when yourCol = "Value"
            then 2
            else 3
       end 
  end as OK
from products
```